# Upgrade Galaxy Note 3 to KitKat 4.4.4

Tags: updates, 4.4-kitkat, samsung-galaxy-note-3

I have Galaxy Note 3 phone, and its last updated software is KitKat 4.4.2, but I heard that Samsung made it official to the Note 3 to be updated to 4.4.4. Does anybody have an idea how to get the update?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your exact model. According to [this unofficial site that provides information about Galaxy Note 3 updates](http://www.galaxynote3update.com/), KitKat 4.4.4 has been available for [specific models](http://www.galaxynote3update.com/t-mobile-galaxy-note-10-1-2014-ota-update/t-mobile-samsung-galaxy-note-10-1-2014-android-4-4-4-update-p607tuvuani1-released/) for a few  weeks, but most models are still on 4.4.2.

Typically, when there's an update available, you should automatically get an OTA update notification that looks like this:

[image]

However, there are two ways to manually check for the latest update:

1. **Settings→Software Update**. If your settings are in tab view, it's on the **More** tab, at the bottom. If you don't see it there, tap **About Phone** or **About Device**, and it should be one of the options in there. If an update is available, you should see a notification like the one above.
2. [Samsung Kies](http://www.samsung.com/us/kies/), a PC application for updating Samsung mobile devices. When Kies detects a connected device, it should automatically inform you of any available updates.

Answer (score 0):

if its actually true then you can go to your settings >> About Phone >> Software Update and Check for updates, the updates that come here are official and will only show up if samsung actually released another version if you really want to do it on you own (custom rom) then you should visit some guys that have these roms available or u can check forums.